# Disable (or restore to default) alternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle property of DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm having a hard time on disabling alternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle, I experimented on this property and now I would like to disable it (or restore it to default) but I don't know how.

I've tried looking at the default value and it looks like this

[image]

But the problem is I can't make my property the same as the default anymore.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I understand, but on the DGV drill into that property (an editor will open) and remove the BackColor you set

Answer (score 1):

Click on this button:

[image: button]

Delete the content of `BackColor` property.

[image: property]

Comment: How about the font? It should be empty, but I can't remove it.

Comment: In VS2010 works exactly the same as `BackColor`: select `Font` property text (i.e.: `Arial; 8,25pt`), delete it and press OK.